# Remote File Transfer from Linux Machine to Windows Machine

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, scp, winscp

I am looking to remotely transfer a file from my Linux machine to a Windows machine. I have done some research and it appears that `scp` is what I want to use to achieve this. However... all of the code that I'm seeing appears to be using cygwin (or similar) that is already installed on the windows machine, hardly "remote." My two systems are completely separate and have their own unique IP addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) or [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/download.php) will do the job. It's required only to have SSH server running on your Linux machine, enabled SSH port (tcp/22 by default) in firewall and your Windows computer must be able to reach the Linux host - you can try `ping <Linux-machine-IP>` from your Windows computer to verify.

If you want something else, you could configure Samba or probably WebDAV (httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dav.html), which allow you to mount your Linux directories as drives in Windows without additional tools. For example, your linux home `/home/user` can be mounted as `Y:` drive in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have an ssh server on your Linux machine, I suggest using [Filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org/), which comes with a GUI.

You just want to install the client on windows, don't bother with the server, a classic ssh server does the job.